# Forbid the user to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

I was thinking if there is a way to gain full control of the page / website by not allowing the user to refresh the page / website in any possible way. I am just curious if that is possible. I know that there are 1 million disadvantages but still.

Best regards,

George S.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to completely forbid the user to refresh/exit the page, because of security concerns. However, you could use the `onbeforeunload` event to prompt them so they have less of a chance of losing work.

Comment: @SpeedyNinja After reading a bunch of articles I notice that it will be almost impossible to do it. I guess good work from the browser developers. My idea was to create an experimental prank page, of course for scientific research only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can intercept a refresh with something like this in which case the user is given a choice...

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){return 'Page refresh has been intercepted to avoid an accidental loss of work';};
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, this method is not really what I tried to achieve in my idea. However, I will give you the best answer because in real world situation this will be the best thing you can do.

Comment: You can write your own custom browser (as I have) with whatever custom behavior you have in mind, using Node-Webkit or NW as they now call it.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently encountered the issue where people were hitting the refresh button couple of times on my website which was eventually causing problems at the server level. I put in some code at the client side to capture it and bypass the submit of the button. Also i put in some code at the server level to have a session entry which would store date time and would compare it when the next request came . it is was within a certain time frame it would be ignored.

```
if(e.which === 116) {
       console.log('blocked');
       return false;
    }
    if(e.which === 82 && e.ctrlKey) {
       console.log('blocked');
       return false;
    }
```

Comment: it is not an answer to your question, just wanted to share it with you.

Comment: I was planning to use these to block the keys from the keyboard. However, my idea was way too impossible to complete. Thanks for sharing your experience. I appreciate it.